# How to convert InputStream to File?

Tags: java, inputstream, html5-audio, fileinputstream, audio-converter

Am receiving an InputStream from a webService that I will then play using the HTML5  tag, so in order to play the audio I need to convert the InputStream to URL so the  tag could read this stream since it dosen't read InputStream.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page import="yourphone.voicemail.*"%>
<%@page import="com.verscom.ws.*"%>
<%@page import="com.verscom.methods.*"%>

<body>
    <button onclick="playSound()">Play Me</button>
    <button onclick="pausrSound()">Pause</button>
    <audio id="audio" controls="controls">
        <source id="mainSrc" type="audio/mp3" onplay="playSound()"></source>
    </audio>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");

function playSound(){ 
<% 
EndUserPortalWSServiceStub.GetVoiceMailMessageVcomResponse[] getvmMsgResp = new EndUserPortalWSServiceStub.GetVoiceMailMessageVcomResponse[2];
EndUserMethods endUserMethods = new EndUserMethods();
getvmMsgResp = endUserMethods.getVoiceMailList();

%>
audio.src= <%=getvmMsgResp[0].getVmailMessageWAVFile().getDataSource().getInputStream().toString()%>;
audio.play(); }

function pausrSound(){ audio.pause(); }

</script>
```

Comment: And the question is? You say "file" then "HTML 5". I highly doubt that the client at the other end will be able to read `file` URIs you produce...

Comment: My question is how to convert from InputStream to URL ? so the HTML audio tag can read the audio on the client side

Comment: Well, do save the file on disk, yes, but then you need to find somewhere on disk which is accessible by your webapp. Do you have a "cache" directory set up already? If yes, save in there. As to making it available to clients, that is up to the mappings you have (one to read from the cache maybe?).

Comment: I have a "cache" directory, but isn't there another way where the audio tag can read this InputStream ?.